Good practice to initiate class member pointer that points to another class?
The whole point of the following program is to see 7 printed on the screen, because m_k is initialized as 1, and then 6 is added to it.
class_bar.hpp
#ifndef TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_BAR_HPP
#define TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_BAR_HPP

#include "iostream"

namespace class_bar
{
namespace class_bar_2
{

class foo;

template <typename T>
class barBase
{
public:
    barBase() = default;
    void barBase_print(int n) // function later gets called to add n to m_k
    {
        m_k += n;
        std::cout << "barBase printing m_k = " << m_k<< std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_k = 1; // m_k initialized as 1
};

class bar : public barBase <int>
{
public:
    bar() = default;
    void bar_print();

private:

};

}   // class_bar_2
}   // bar

#endif //TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_BAR_HPP

class_bar.cpp
#include "../include/class_bar.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace class_bar
{
namespace class_bar_2
{

void bar::bar_print()
{
    std::cout << "bar printing" << std::endl;
}

}   // class_bar2
}   // class_bar

class_foo.hpp
#ifndef TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_FOO_HPP
#define TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_FOO_HPP    
#include "stdio.h"

// forward declaration
namespace class_bar
{
namespace class_bar_2
{
class bar;
}
}

using namespace class_bar::class_bar_2;

// class foo
namespace class_foo
{

class foo
{
public:
    foo() = default;
    void foo_print_from_bar();

private:
    bar* m_b = NULL; // member point of class foo that points to class bar
};
}

#endif //TWOCLASSUSEEACHOTHER_CLASS_FOO_HPP

class_foo.cpp
#include "../include/class_foo.hpp"
#include "../include/class_bar.hpp"

#include <iostream>

namespace class_foo
{
void foo::foo_print_from_bar()
{
    std::cout << "foo print using ";
    m_b->barBase_print(6); // method of class barBase to do addition and pinting
}
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "include/class_foo.hpp"
#include "include/class_bar.hpp"

int main()
{
    class_foo::foo f;

    f.foo_print_from_bar(); // foo calls bar to print

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

When running main.cpp, error pops:
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV)

This is because of the NULL pointer
My questions is, what is a good practice to initialize m_b/bar, so that m_k is initialized as 1? Obviously I don't want any memory leak, so is smart pointer a solution? If so how do I use it? Some code samples would be really appreciated.

It's not clear why you have a pointer to bar instead of just a bar. If you have a pointer, you need to check that it's actually pointing at something before dereferencing it. Since you don't have a bar instance in your code, it's hard to say when to assign the pointer. If the bar instance is not available when you create your foo, you need some way of assigning to the pointer later. Also, don't use NULL (if you are using C++11 or later). Use nullptr.

Note: At this point bar makes no use of foo, so the trivial answer is to do what Ted recommends, but I doubt you would be asking this question in that case. One of foo or bar can directly contain the other, but yes, the other needs a pointer or reference. You need to decide which of the two has to take the hit, and if you come to the conclusion that bar really doesn't need foo, you're back to Ted's approach. If not, we can't really help much unless you give us more information on bar's relationship with foo.

@user4581301That makes sense. Thank you.

foo::m_b is not pointing at a valid bar object when you call m_b->barBase_print(), hence the crash.
You can pass a bar& reference or bar* pointer to foo's constructor to initialize m_b, and then main() can create a bar instance to construct f with, eg:
class foo
{
public:
    foo(bar& b); // or: foo(bar* b);
    void foo_print_from_bar();

private:
    bar* m_b = NULL; // member point of class foo that points to class bar
};

foo::foo(bar& b) : m_b(&b) {}
// or:
// foo::foo(bar* b) : m_b(b) {}

void foo::foo_print_from_bar()
{
    std::cout << "foo print using ";
    m_b->barBase_print(6); // method of class barBase to do addition and pinting
}

int main()
{
    class_bar::class_bar_2::bar b;
    class_foo::foo f(b); // or: foo f(&b);

    f.foo_print_from_bar(); // foo calls bar to print

    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


It works. Thank you so much!
